# Proof that a Proof-of-work was computed on a specific machine?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, blockchain

When a server sends a proof-of-work to a client, is there a way to somewhat guarantee that the PoW was done by that client and not another one? ie: the challenge was transferred to a third-party/ASIC computer?

I mainly want something to be computed inside the browser but even if it was in GO or C#, since the client can never be trusted... I don't believe this can be done. I believe I can only verify if the response comes from the same IP which requested the challenge.

Is that correct?

Comment: *I don't believe this can be done* I agree with you, anything you communicate to the client, the client can communicate the same thing to some other machine, and respond with the other machine's response when finished.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yea I figured but I wouldn't have slept if I didn't ask :) it was bugging me

Comment: Most easiest way: use tuple (your_IP, server_ID, timestamp, nonce) as seed for PoW hash. As result, server can verify your PoW and typle, and be sure: your PoW dedicated to this server only.